How can I increase my counter and have it persist across scenes and runtime?
I am working on persistence and have an issue where a counter is not persisting across scenes and runtimes. I have a counter, and it goes up in on scene, but does not show changes when going to other scenes. I am using DontDestroyOnLoad and PlayerPrefs.
https://gdl.space/aguxobupov.cs Muon object where the player interacts which would cause the number from other scenes like the stage select to go up
https://gdl.space/izumaxitiz.cpp counter in the play game which at first were used for coin counting
https://gdl.space/rifuwociwo.cs Muon counter which counts how many muons from each stage you have rescued

Please embed your code directly in your question here, not in an external link. Visit the [help] if you need support formatting your code correctly.

You don't have any piece of code that actually calls load and save. You don't use as well the gamedata from those functions that you hand as parameter

This is my first answer, so I'll try my best.
It was hard to understand the code so this is a generic approach for both problems:

(data) persisting across scenes and runtimes

Data persist between scenes
Since you are using a Singleton-like pattern I suggest you to see this post.
A simpler way is to use static variables.
(good to say that you can't see static variables in inspector)
public class ObjectCounter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int CurrentObjects;
    public static int TotalObjects;
    // Update at the same time as TotalObjects to see in inspector
    [SerializeField] int totalObjects; 
}

Then access with
newCounter = ObjectCounter.CurrentObjects;

Most likely you'll have to update elements that relies on static values when changing scene, like UI.
Static Variables: The data persists for the lifetime of the application. Static fields and properties are shared across all instances of the class and are associated with the type itself rather than any specific instance
There are better aproaches for this, but to keep it simple.

Load Save between Sessions
This is trickier because there are a lot of ways to do it.
This one uses PlayerPrefs, to maintain original scheme.
As @zibelas said, there is no code where you call Load and Save, so this solutions implements it, using JSON.
public class LoadSaveData : Monobehaviour
{
    public PlayerData playerData = new PlayerData();

    public void Awake()
    {
        LoadPlayerData();
    }

    public void SaveObjects(int currentObjects, int totalObjects)
    {
        playerData.currentObjects = currentObjects;
        playerData.totalObjects = totalObjects;
    }

    public void LoadPlayerData()
    {
        string jsonData = PlayerPrefs.GetString("PlayerData");
        
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonData)) return;

        playerData = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayerData>(jsonData);
        
        Debug.Log("Player data loaded.");
    }

    void SavePlayerData()
    {
        saveData.Invoke();
        
        string jsonData = JsonUtility.ToJson(playerData);

        PlayerPrefs.SetString("PlayerData", jsonData);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        
        Debug.Log("Player data saved.");
    }
}

Then the class with the actual data.
[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerData
{
    public int currentObjects;
    public int totalObjects;
}

Then in the main script. (add previous variables)
public class ObjectCounter : Monobehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] LoadSaveData loadSaveData;

    void Start()
    {
        currentObjects = loadSaveData.playerData.currentObjects;
        totalObjects = loadSaveData.playerData.totalObjects;
    }

    void SaveData()
    {
        loadSaveData.SaveObjects(currentObjects, totalObjects);
    }
}


Forgot to say: Use SavePlayerData(), I like it in OnApplicationQuit()
You can use second method for both problems but its not the optimal.
